# how to prevent this function to be executed more than 2 times in x miliseconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, double-submit-prevention

how can i prevent this to be executed twice when i get to the bottom of the scroll?

```
 if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
                   last_msg_funtion();
 }
```

Options i see:

I tried setting a var loading_already == false and, something **like**:

```
if(loading_already==false){
     loading_already = true;
     last_msg_function();
     setTimeout('refresh_loading',300);
}
```

where

```
function refresh_loading(){ loading_already = false; }
```

But didn't work out, any suggestion for this?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

loading_already = true;

You have == which is boolean is operator, not assignment.

Comment: i live rote that so it was a live mistake, thanks. but in my code was ok. should it work?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the awesome [jQuery throttle/debounce plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/). Makes this sort of thing very easy.

The following example will ensure that `las_msg_function` is called no more than once every 250 milliseconds (assuming your scroll detection expression is correct);

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
  $.throttle(250, las_msg_function);
}
```

Here's [an example page](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/examples/throttle/) which shows how this is used in conjunction with scroll detection (look at second example)

Comment: j is undefined
[Interrumpir en este error] (function(b,c){var $=b.jQuery||b.C...d,e,false):a(d,f,e!==false)}})(this);

Comment: and its only executed if like: $.throttle(250, last_msg_funtion());

Comment: `$.throttle(250, last_msg_funtion());` is not the correct syntax. Read more here: http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce/docs/files/jquery-ba-throttle-debounce-js.html